# How to hide a div when the user clicks body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this code:

```
function check_remember(event) {
 if (document.getElementById('rem_email').value == "") {
        alert("Harap isi email !");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "none";
        event.preventDefault();
    }

};

function remember_show() {
    document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "block";
};
```

and this my html :

```
<button type="button" class="btn-custom remember" onclick="remember_show()">Ingatkan Saya</button>

<!-- PopUp -->
<div id="popup_remember">
  <div id="REM">
    <form id="form_remember">
      <input id="rem_email" name="email" placeholder="Input Email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
        <input type="submit" id="sub_rem" value="Agree" onclick="check_remember(event)">
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, i do not know how to when click body modal will hide..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get clicked target. Then check if the click event is out of popup div and if it is hidden already. Something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(arguments[0].target);
        var $target = $('#popup_remember');
        if( !$this.parents('#popup_remember').length && $this.attr('id') != "REM" && $target.is(':visible') ) $target.hide();
    });
});
```

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/rmtek3a9/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in css i set #popup_remember to width 100%, when i click outside div#REM it does not work. i think because i set #popup_remember to width 100% and z-index 9999. please correct me :)

Comment: It should work anyway (if you click out popup div), but I had an error in the code. I edited it already.

Comment: if i set #popup_remember width and height 50%, its work. [this my css jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmtek3a9/3/) , because i click outside #popup_remember. but if you have other way to my css. please correct me

Comment: I see what happens, you just want a modal background. I updated my answer and fiddle, it works as expected now. As you use a modal, we have to handle its wrapper div `#REM`.

Comment: oh great, your my hero.. i have already 3 hours waste my time on this case.

see and read other forum, but its does not work. and i try to ask here. finallu its work. Thank you @kmsdev

Comment: I am glad. Anyway, there are more approaches that you could do to improve it playing with some css. For example, you can have two siblings divs, first one the background modal, second the wrapper. So, clicking into wrapper never handles the modal, and vice versa .)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you looking for:

[WORKING : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r94uv49e/)

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r94uv49e/2/)

**HTML**

```
<h1> Just Random Header </h1>

<div class="div1"> Hello i am div :) <br /> <br />If you click anywhere then me i will disappear !</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1
{
    width:310px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".div1");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i think my css which led to this all does not work. this my popup when i display it [this my css jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmtek3a9/3/) , please correct me.

Comment: Sloved! see the demo here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmtek3a9/4/). If still any issues feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jQuery instead of just Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', function(){
        if($('#rem_email').val() === ''){
            alert('Harap isi email !');
        } else {
            $('#popup_remember').hide()
        }
    }
    //Let's add your remember_show function too! It's also an OnClick (As seen in the HTML).
    $('btn-custom remember').on('click',function(){
        $('popup_remember').show();
    });
});
```

That's your javascript code converted to jQuery. :)

Instead of `hide()` and `show()`, you can also use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` to animate the opacity of the object you are hiding and showing.

Comment: There is nothing bad in using Vanilla JS over the jQuery! To be honest I would recommend to use pure JS before start learn or use any of it's frameworks.

Comment: I know that! That's exactly what I did when I started with js/jQuery, so I couldn't agree more when it comes to learning purposes. There's that 'Try' keyword in my first sentence too haha. I just find jQuery short and readable nowadays so it fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript too:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-custom remember" onclick="remember_show(event)">Ingatkan Saya</button>
```

Pass the event in the arguments of the calling function. Then you need to add `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the event to bubble up in the DOM tree.

```
function check_remember(event) {

    if (document.getElementById('rem_email').value == "") {
        alert("Harap isi email !");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "none";
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    event.stopPropagation();  //<----add this to stop the event to bubble up.

};

function remember_show(event) {
    document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "block";
    event.stopPropagation(); //<----add this to stop the event to bubble up.
};
```

Now add a event listener on the `body` like:

```
function hideModal(e){
    document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "none";
    event.stopPropagation();
}

document.addEventListener('click', hideModal, false);
```

---

### Sample Demo:

---

```js
function check_remember(event) {
  if (document.getElementById('rem_email').value == "") {
    alert("Harap isi email !");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "none";
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
};

function remember_show(event) {
  document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "block";
  event.stopPropagation();
};

function hideModal(e) {
  document.getElementById('popup_remember').style.display = "none";
  event.stopPropagation();
}

var body = document;

body.addEventListener('click', hideModal, false);
```

```css
#popup_remember {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-custom remember" onclick="remember_show(event)">Ingatkan Saya</button>

<!-- PopUp -->
<div id="popup_remember">
  <div id="REM">
    <form id="form_remember">
      <input id="rem_email" name="email" placeholder="Input Email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
      <input type="submit" id="sub_rem" value="Agree" onclick="check_remember(event)">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to make custom modal this may helps you. But this is only for the modal effect and your problem about clicking the `body` and it will close the modal. [JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/f1c2sghw/)

Hope it helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: also this is using jQuery :)